# How to cluster data points to predefined regions?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

(Matlab question)

I have a set of data points that I want to cluster to predefined points.

My data points are a MxN matrix. Each row M is a curve. I want to assign each curve to a given set of curves PxN. E.g. P=5, 5 sought after curves.

So in the end it should assign each curve of MxN to a curve in PxN.

The easiest I could come up was using kmeans with 0 iteration. 
Using correlations gave me poor results.
Is there a easy method in Matlab do to that ?

Many thanks for answering.
Cheers
Jimbo

Comment: Solved it myself:
    
    for WC=1:length(DataSet(:,1))
    
        for i=1:length(centers(:,1))
            
            dist(i,WC) = sum( ((DataSet(WC,T) - centers(i,T)).^2));
        end
           [temp, idx_temp] = min(dist(:,WC))
        
           idx_dcb(WC) = idx_temp;
        
  
end

Comment: "Clustering" means the algorithm has to infer the cluster structure. You want to do classification: label points with predefined classes. Try nearest-neighbor classification.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself, something like that

```
T=1:360
centers = rand(4,360)
DataSet =  rand(200,360)

    for WC=1:length(DataSet(:,1))

        for i=1:length(centers(:,1))

            dist(i,WC) = sum( ((DataSet(WC,T) - centers(i,T)).^2));
        end
           [temp, idx_temp] = min(dist(:,WC))

           idx_dcb(WC) = idx_temp;  
    end
```

idx_dcb is the indices of your assigned group.

Comment: Using shorted distance